# Nodejs Function is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am coding a small chatbot with facebook messenger.

I created 2 main js file:
facebook.js and control.js

facebook.js will perform send message/ receive message.
control.js will perform some minor logic/ application function.

Let me give a example code for these two js.

In facebook.js

```js
function sendMessage(){
  ///configuring and json format
  //send to facebook server(webhook) by using Bluebird
  return new bluebird(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(data);
  }
}

// exports sendMessage()
module.exports = {
sendMessage:sendMessage
}
```

control.js

```js
var fb = require('./facebook');




function something(){
  fb.sendMessage();
}
```

When i trigger the somthing(). The console show the error like this

> #### System Error ### : uncaughtException: fb.sendMessage is not a function TypeError: fb.sendMessage is not a function

I log the 'fb':
it print {} in console.
Anyone facing this error? am i code wrong way to exports the function?

Comment: Try addding require("./facebook").... notice the dot(.) in filepath

Comment: Have you double checked orthograph? `fucntion somthing` alone has two typos. Also the real code is missing (`fb.sendFullBranchLink`).

Comment: @LorenzMeyer this is my typos. thanks

Comment: p.s  i tried to execute sendMessage() in facebook.js. It works. But exports to another js and got the error message...

Comment: Just to be sure....1) Are both the files in the same directory? 2) Is there any other variable declaration interfering with variable 'fb'

Comment: @riyaz_ali 1.yes 2.just declared 1 'fb' var

Comment: try logging  the fb object in main.js `console.log(fb)` and check the output

Comment: Thanks, i think i got the point. I print out "fb". It seem not export the function. It show {}

Answer (score 1):

Because when i print out the "fb" .It shows empty {}

I found that is problem of circular dependency!
Which means you have 2 module(Ma and Mb). 
Module B required by Module A. Also, Module A required by Module B

More info:
[enter link description here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles)